# any recommendations for a dethatcher?

Tags: lawn-repair, equipment

I believe my lawn has significant amount of thatch build up and so am shopping around for a dethatcher/scarifier.

What features are important to consider in a dethatcher to be used for a medium to large size lawn?

**Updated**:
Based on [@Stephie](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/7456/stephie)'s suggestion, here are the features am looking for:

1. I have a medium sized lawn. I see the thatch got built up in 3 years since we moved in. So, I am planning to dethatch once every year depending on the thatch level if it is more than 1/2".
2. I am looking at electric or battery powered. Please suggest if you have any recommended ones in gas powered as well.
3. For electric/battery powered - what are the things that I need to look for?
4. [@dandavis](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/35205/dandavis) - I see your point as well. I believe I have Kentucky bluegrass and renting one time is costing almost 80% of some models (Sun Joe/Greenworks/Worx). So I thought I would own one and dethatch at my will.

Comment: Welcome! Note that [shopping advice is not suitable for the SE system](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for a bunch of reasons, e.g. because it gets outdated and is regional. Asking for features or what is important to consider on the other hand is perfectly fine.

Comment: Btw, you may want to add a few details, e.g. what do you consider a “medium to large” lawn? I have a hunch that depending on where you and other users are in the world, the definition may vary wildly.

Comment: If gasoline powered, make sure the exhaust pipe is not directed at the operator.

Comment: unless you have kentucky bluegrass, I would rent big one that made short work of the job. Other grasses typically only need dethatched every 3-5 years. You don't want to buy a big expensive one for that little of use, and you don't want to buy a little electric toy that takes 3 afternoons to complete the job either.